# Which is the best way to get the location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, maps

My goal is to use the latitude and longitude in my application. I have found two effective ways of doing it for my purpose after googling all day long.

Should I use:

```
lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
```

or should I instead constantly check for updates and store those updates in a variable?

```
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

and in my location listener I can store the latitude and longitude every two seconds, so that whenever I need to use it, I can use that. Which one?

**What are the benefits of each? I know that the first way is null a lot more often, so should I use the first one when it is not null and the second one when null?** Could the last known location ever be more accurate than the update from GPS provider?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Places FusedApi to get location like this:-

```
   mylocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (locationRequest != null) {
        lat.setText("latitude" + String.valueOf(mylocation.getLatitude()));
        log.setText("longitude" + String.valueOf(mylocation.getLongitude()));
    }
```

Refer here for more http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/